# Is there a way to search by partial phone number in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, contacts

I'm trying to search my contacts to match a partial number (four digits) to a name. Is this possible?

Comment: George's answer below is correct; I just don't know why it isn't working for all contacts on my iPhone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search your contacts by partial phone number using Spotlight.

[image]

Comment: Partial numbers don't work. I have a contact with the number, ###-454-####. Typing 454 in Spotlight doesn't return the contact.

Comment: @Seth It works for UK numbers, as shown above (the actual number is ##### 119908. The above also worked as I was typing, filtering down from each number I entered (e.g. 119 matches the above contact, along with a few others with those digits). I don't have any US phone numbers on my phone to test.

Comment: Thank you for being persistent. Now I see that it works for some of my contacts, but not for all of them. I haven't been able to identify a common characteristic of the ones that don't work. Any ideas?

Comment: @Seth Strange, it seems to work fine with all my contacts. Do you have multiple accounts, and could that be related (i.e. are some contacts on iCloud and they work, and ones on Exchange don't?)

Comment: That's most likely the problem. I have a lot of connected accounts on my phone. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This works for some, but not all, numbers.  Even within the same contact.  Sometimes, that mobile numbers are in the results, but land-lines are not?  Other times, both numbers are.  I even found one case with two mobiles, and one land.  Only one mobile number shows up in spotlight.  Am very curious about how the index is built.

Comment: If I go to Messages, start a new message, and type in a substring of a phone number in my contacts, I get a list of matches. For example, if I type in `1234` I get a pick list of all numbers containing `1234`. Note, that this does *not* match the number `312-345-9999`. So it is not perfect.